# using EMC branded disk array with Dell/EMC branded CX3-20 head unit

Tags: storage-area-network, dell, emc, clariion

Are there any problems or gotchas with using an EMC branded DAE3P with a Dell/EMC branded Clariion SAN? Obviously getting support for the array would be problematic, but other than that is there anything I should know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I'd simply ask Dell what their support position would be. If you have one of their branded CX series arrays then you should have Mission Critical support and my experience with Dell's Clariion support has been that they will be quite clear with you one way or the other if you just ask them. From a technical point of view there is absolutely no good reason for them to object, Dell don't do anything to the Clariion kit apart from changing the badge.

Comment: I confirmed with Dell that there is no technical reason that the EMC branded DAE could not be used with Dell/EMC branded equipment. They will also continue to support the rest of the san, no problem there. I installed it, no problems.